# Is it possible to connect to router through ssh?

Tags: networking, ssh

I have a WiFi-router (cisco linksys) at my job and I have to access the database of our website frequently, but the access to the database is restricted and is only possible from my workplace. I read that some routers are "equipped" with ssh server (which appears to the the case at my workplace), so my question would be, it is actually possible to access router from outside via ssh and then connect database as if I'm doing it from workplace network, if router is told to have ssh feature?

Sorry for my broken explanation of the problem, improvements are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is a rooter?

Comment: WiFi-Router is a device that has an incoming DSL connection and serves as a WiFi-hotspot for this connection and allows you to manage this connection in some way (DNS settings etc).

Comment: Or did you try to point out an obvious mistake I made in the question? Then it's fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is actually possible to access router from outside via ssh and then connect database as if I'm doing it from workplace network, if router is told to have ssh feature?

You can ssh to your router, provided the configuration is correct. I doubt that your router has a query tool for your database though.

You should use the router as a proxy, a mere hop, to connect to your work machine.

Another possibility is to tunnel the usual remote desktop protocols through ssh / the router, that way you can connect to your work machine using RDP, X11, vnc, whatever...

Comment: Somehow like [this](http://www.cisco.com/c/dam/en/us/td/i/000001-100000/85001-90000/88001-89000/88125.ps/_jcr_content/renditions/88125.jpg)?

Comment: More or less, yes. Have you tried asking the IT people at your workplace if they provide remote access? Perhaps you can connect via a VPN?

Comment: The protocols you have listed, do they need a separate machine at the workplace for me to access the network?

Comment: I dug a little in Google and I think that creating VPN tunnel might work. But still a silly thing I don't quite get: if we connect our routers via VPN tunnel, then we kind of have a shared network, but how to tell, who is the host? I mean like, when I arrange a tunnel, how do you determine whether people from my workplace are browsing through my connection at home or I browse through their connection at office?

Comment: If you connect to your work router using a VPN, then your home computer effectively becomes part of the office network. It would be as if you took your home computer to your office and plug in into a network wall outlet there.